# Search and replace special character in a string in scala

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

In scala ,I have a string where I need to replace `%23` with `#`  , as below:

From    `https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/%23%23%23ENVIRONMENT_NAME%23%23%23/abc/template_abc_windows_%23%23%23ENVIRONMENT_NAME%23%23%23.zip?X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEOghsfgdghgkjkjjklj`

to    `https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/###ENVIRONMENT_NAME###/abc/template_abc_windows_###ENVIRONMENT_NAME###.zip?X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEOghsfgdghgkjkjjklj`

I have used below regex and logic for substitution but I get error as:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

Code:

```
val originalURL = "https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/%23%23%23ENVIRONMENT_NAME%23%23%23/abc/template_abc_windows_%23%23%23ENVIRONMENT_NAME%23%23%23.zip?X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEOghsfgdghgkjkjjklj"

  val pattern = Pattern.compile("(https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/)((%23){3})([a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+)((%23){3})(/abc/template_abc_windows_)((%23){3})([a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+)((%23){3})(..*)")
  val matcher = pattern.matcher(originalURL)
  val replacedURL = matcher.group(1)+"###"+ matcher.group(4)+"###"+ matcher.group(7)+"###"+ matcher.group(10)+"###"+matcher.group(13)
  println("*******replacedURL*******  => "+ replacedURL)
```

Any help is much appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: string.replaceAll("%23", "#")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just use `String.replaceAll`?

```
val url = "https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/%23%23%23ENVIRONMENT_NAME%23%23%23/abc/template_abc_windows_%23%23%23ENVIRONMENT_NAME%23%23%23.zip?X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEOghsfgdghgkjkjjklj"
url.replaceAll("%23", "#")
```

Comment: This substitutes the 1st `%23%` and resulting url looks like:
`https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/#23%23ENVIRONMENT_NAME#23%23/abc/template_abc_windows_#23%23ENVIRONMENT_NAME#23%23.zip?X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEO`.

So I did something like this:

`val originalURL = "https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/%23%23%23ENVIRONMENT_NAME%23%23%23/abc/template_abc_windows_%23%23%23ENVIRONMENT_NAME%23%23%23.zip?X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEO"

  val replacedURL = originalURL.replaceAll("%23%23%23", "###")`
This worked.
Thank you @Krzysztof Atłasik

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I had typo. It's now corrected.